# Is there a way in Android to clear the app data without crashing the app? If not, how can I automatically launch the app again?

Tags: android, caching, kotlin

I am trying to clear the data by using:

```
(ContextHack.appContext().getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE) as ActivityManager).clearApplicationUserData()
```

but it causes a crash. Do you know a better approach?

Basically I want unpair a BT device and when doing that, clear all the data, without crashing the app.

```
 pairingButton.setOnClickListener {

                        val alertDialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this.activity!!)
                        alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.dialog_logo)
                        alertDialog.setTitle(Strings.unpairWatchConfirmation)
                        alertDialog.setMessage(Strings.unpairWatchConfirmationMsg)

                        alertDialog.setPositiveButton(Strings.confirmAction) { dialog, id ->
                            (ContextHack.appContext().getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE) as ActivityManager)
                                   .clearApplicationUserData()
                            activity!!.toast(Strings.watchRemoved)
                        }
                        alertDialog.setNegativeButton(Strings.cancel) { dialog, id ->
                            dialog.dismiss()
                        }
                        alertDialog.show()
                    }
```

Comment: Where alertDialog.create() ? Show crash logcat. If you can

Comment: Is it crashing (with an Exception), or is Android force closing it? Android always force closes apps when you clear the data through the settings. Probably because it will possibly be in an invalid state. I think you should clear the data manually.

Comment: i think your `this.activity!!` is probably null

Comment: It is Android force closing it yes..

Answer (score 0):

Clearing memory causes an app to be closed, because when you delete files out from under it it may be in a bad state.  Instead, since this is your own app, just write a function to start from the base of your internal storage and walk the directory structure deleting every file.

Answer (score 0):

```
1. You can call this method[deleteAppData()] to clear app cache:

    public static void deleteAppData(Context context) {
 try {
 File dir = context.getCacheDir();
 deleteDir(dir);
 } catch (Exception e) {}
}

public static boolean deleteDir(File dir) {
 if (dir != null && dir.isDirectory()) {
 String[] children = dir.list();

 for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
 boolean success = deleteDir(new File(dir, children[i]));
 if (!success) {
 return false;
 }

 }
 return dir.delete();
 } else if(dir!= null && dir.isFile()) {
 return dir.delete();
 } else {
 return false;
 }

}
```